# How to change the size of a CSS shape + add a border?

Tags: css, css-shapes

How do I make the heart smaller?  When I change the width/height in #heart (the first few lines), nothing really changes except the location.  Any advice?

Additionally, right now the heart is filled in red.  When I add

```
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:5px;
```

the heart border looks funny.  Advice on how to fix this as well?

```
/*CSS for Heart*/
    #heart {
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
        height: 90px;
    }
    #heart:before,
    #heart:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        left: 50px;
        top: 0;
        width: 50px;
        height: 80px;
        background: red;
        -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
        border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
           -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
             -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
                transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
           -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
            -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
             -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
                transform-origin: 0 100%;
    }
    #heart:after {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
           -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
             -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
           -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
            -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
             -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
                transform-origin :100% 100%;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with how the heart looks but look at the comments in my fiddle to see how to change the size, http://jsfiddle.net/AV4xv/.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that the CSS shape is made of 2 layers that look like a bullet and are just rotated and position side-by-side to make it look like a heart. Any borders added to this are going to be just applied to the bullet and not the shape itself. If you wanted to achieve a border around the whole thing you'd have to fake it with another heart behind it.

I've just added this pen to show you how to fake a border of sorts and to also show you the bullet shape with a different color: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydGHu

Edit: adding one with just a rectangle covering up the extra border as suggested by @Christoph http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eoxwr

Comment: +1 good explanation and solution, although you don't need a second shape, an overlying square to cover the unwanted border would be sufficient too.

Comment: Good suggestion, I didn't think of that at first, I've added a new pen to show this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to make it smaller by changing:

```
left: 25px;
width: 25px;
height: 40px;
```

Here I have an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dVLUb/

Comment: I can only think about making two slightly different hearts one on top of another. :) Or You can always use javascript canvas.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the size of the heart you have to recalulate all relevant properties like `width , height, left , border-radius` for this element in proportion.

The example shows the heart in half size: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uBqPw/)